# Get elements in XSD

Tags: php, xml, xsd

I have an PHP code that makes a call to a webservice and returns a XSD, but I don't know how to read its elements. What would be the best way?
I've searched and ended up with DOMDocuments, but I didn't understood it quite well. Is that the best way?

**EDIT** - Ok, I was able to get my xsd to a DOMDocument, now how can I get, for example, the value from node CATEGORIA in the second product?

Here is the code it returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet xmlns="http://">
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns=""     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="Produtos">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="TIMESTAMP" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DEPARTAMENTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="CATEGORIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="SUBCATEGORIA" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="FABRICANTE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="CODIGO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DESCRICAO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DESCRTEC" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PARTNUMBER" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="EAN" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="GARANTIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PESOKG" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PRECOREVENDA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PRECOSEMST" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DATAVALIDADEPRECO" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="DISPONIVEL" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="URLFOTOPRODUTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ESTOQUE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="NCM" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="LARGURA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ALTURA" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="PROFUNDIDADE" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ATIVO" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="SUBSTTRIBUTARIA" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ORIGEMPRODUTO" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                            <xs:element name="ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
        <Produtos diffgr:id="Produtos1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                <TIMESTAMP>2017-08-11T11:09:26-03:00</TIMESTAMP>
                <DEPARTAMENTO></DEPARTAMENTO>
                <CATEGORIA></CATEGORIA>
                <SUBCATEGORIA></SUBCATEGORIA>
                <FABRICANTE>GENIUS</FABRICANTE>
                <CODIGO>0064703</CODIGO>
                <DESCRICAO></DESCRICAO>
                <DESCRTEC></DESCRTEC>
                <PARTNUMBER>31731047103</PARTNUMBER>
                <EAN>4710268244738</EAN>
                <GARANTIA>12</GARANTIA>
                <PESOKG>3.1000</PESOKG>
                <PRECOREVENDA>95.0000</PRECOREVENDA>
                <PRECOSEMST>95.0000</PRECOSEMST>
                <DATAVALIDADEPRECO></DATAVALIDADEPRECO>
                <DISPONIVEL>1</DISPONIVEL>
                <URLFOTOPRODUTO></URLFOTOPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUE>RJ</ESTOQUE>
                <NCM></NCM>
                <LARGURA>0.3000</LARGURA>
                <ALTURA>0.3500</ALTURA>
                <PROFUNDIDADE>0.1700</PROFUNDIDADE>
                <ATIVO>1</ATIVO>
                <SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>0</SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>
                <ORIGEMPRODUTO></ORIGEMPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>63.0000</ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>
            </Produtos>
            <Produtos diffgr:id="Produtos2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                <TIMESTAMP>2017-08-14T18:01:00-03:00</TIMESTAMP>
                <DEPARTAMENTO></DEPARTAMENTO>
                <CATEGORIA></CATEGORIA>
                <SUBCATEGORIA></SUBCATEGORIA>
                <FABRICANTE>GENIUS</FABRICANTE>
                <CODIGO>0064694</CODIGO>
                <DESCRICAO></DESCRICAO>
                <DESCRTEC></DESCRTEC>
                <PARTNUMBER>31731006100</PARTNUMBER>
                <EAN>4710268238461</EAN>
                <GARANTIA>12</GARANTIA>
                <PESOKG>0.4900</PESOKG>
                <PRECOREVENDA>28.9900</PRECOREVENDA>
                <PRECOSEMST>28.9900</PRECOSEMST>
                <DATAVALIDADEPRECO></DATAVALIDADEPRECO>
                <DISPONIVEL>1</DISPONIVEL>
                <URLFOTOPRODUTO></URLFOTOPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUE>RJ</ESTOQUE>
                <NCM>85182100            </NCM>
                <LARGURA>0.1500</LARGURA>
                <ALTURA>0.1200</ALTURA>
                <PROFUNDIDADE>0.0700</PROFUNDIDADE>
                <ATIVO>1</ATIVO>
                <SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>0</SUBSTTRIBUTARIA>
                <ORIGEMPRODUTO></ORIGEMPRODUTO>
                <ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>100.0000</ESTOQUEDISPONIVEL>
            </Produtos>
        </NewDataSet>
    </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Its in portuguese, but I think you guys can understand what is what. It returns me around 20 Products, and I need to make use of each of those informations

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!! Turned my XSD into an array with code below

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
    $doc->loadXML($response);
    $doc->save('t.xml');

    $xmlfile  = file_get_contents('t.xml');
    $parseObj = str_replace($doc->lastChild->prefix.':',"",$xmlfile);
    $ob       = simplexml_load_string($parseObj);
    $data     = json_decode(json_encode($ob), true);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've managed to get what you want, but to use SimpleXML and XPath properly...

```
<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set ( 'display_errors', 1 );

$xsd = simplexml_load_file("t1.xml");
$xsd->registerXPathNamespace("xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
$elements = $xsd->xpath("//xs:element[@minOccurs]");
foreach ( $elements as $element )   {
    echo "Element name: ".$element['name'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to approach this, the one is DOM and the other is SAX.
DOM requires the whole document to be read before processing it,
where as SAX is event based and events get fired as soon as it finds something that you are interested as the document is read.

Tree-Based Parsers vs Event-Based Parsers

Please see this page for a quick tutorial:
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parsers.asp)

```
<?php
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("note.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item) {
   print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I already solved it, gonna post as an answer. As I need basically all values, I used DOM.